# how to display alert message only once?

Tags: javascript

This is my code to make when click close button then save at localStorage to don't display again:

```
$('#myAlert .close').on('click', function() {
    $('#myAlert').fadeOut(300);
    if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
        localStorage.setItem('alert-closed', true);
        localStorage.removeItem("hidden"); 
    }
});
```

The problem that I can't make it display only once, How can make this?

Comment: just check localstorage if the alert-closed item is set

Comment: @DZDomi Can you give me an example ? thanks.

Comment: What is purpose of `if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange `if` statements, check if `localStorage` is `undefined`, also if `localStorage.getItem("alert-closed")` is equal to `null` before attaching `click` event to element.

```
  $(function() {
    if (typeof localStorage !== undefined) {
      if (localStorage.getItem("alert-cosed") === null) {
        $('#myAlert .close').on('click', function() {
          $('#myAlert').fadeOut(300);    
          localStorage.setItem('alert-closed', true);
          localStorage.removeItem("hidden"); 
        }); 
      }
    } else {
        alert("`localStorage is `undefined`")
    }
  });
```